# ComVisible C# DLL causing Error 438 in VB6.0

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, com-interop

i've written a DLL in C# (.NET v4) which I want to use in a VB6.0 Projekt. I basicly followed the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms227568(v=vs.80).aspx and ended up with this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate
{
    [Serializable]
    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("F5DCE88F-AD38-4a9a-9A69-0F8DC0EDB4E3")]
    public class ExchangeUfl : IExchangeUfl
    {
        public double ConvertUSDollarsToCDN(double usd)
        {
            return (usd * 1.45);
        }

        public void bla()
        {
        }

        public string t2()
        {
            return "t2";
        }

        public String test()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

and this Interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate
{
    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("F6B3D6DB-E4C8-48A9-B9B5-324012E2E93F")]
    interface IExchangeUfl
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        double ConvertUSDollarsToCDN(double usd);

        [DispId(2)]
        String test();

        [DispId(3)]
        string t2();

        [DispId(4)]
        void bla();
    }
}
```

My AssemblyInfo.cs look like this

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Microsoft 2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: Guid("912fe53d-dfc9-4eec-bbca-7f2ed29d95dc")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I've turned on the strong name signing in the project properties and the COM-Interopt registration is off.

I created the project and registered the DLL via "regasm.ex C:\path\to\the\lib.dll /codebase" and it shows up in the GAC (i'm using RegDllView from www.nirsoft.net)

In the VB project I can create the object, so i assume the registration works properly.
But when i call one of the methods i got a Run-time error ‘438’: Object doesn’t support this property or method

My VB Code looks like this:

```
Dim testi As Object
Dim fab As Object
Set fab = CreateObject("CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate.ExchangeUfl")
Set testi = fab.t2()
```

It doesnt matter which method i call, i always get the same error :(
Am I missing something? Have I done something wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: "it shows up in the GAC" is drastically wrong and completely incompatible with Regasm's /codebase option.  Remove it from the GAC so you can be sure that your VB6 program won't use an old version of the DLL that doesn't have the member yet.

Comment: Hm, the registered file was in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate\v4.0_1.0.0.0__e0‌​a5a78a5fa397d9\CRUFL_CS_ExchangeRate.dll and a few days old and very likely an outdated version missing the methods. I removed it and re-registered the DLL. Now it points to my c# project directory. Seems quite good, but i get "Automatisierungsfehler. Das System konnte die angegebene Datei nicht finden." (something like "automatization error. system could not find the file")?!

Comment: Use SysInterals' Process Monitor to see where it looks for the file.

Comment: I suggest you start by scratch using a VB.Net ComClass template and then if needed switch to C#. The VB.Net ComClasses work out of the box and we use them for more than two years now in production. Be sure to use new names so that no confusion is possible with the previous classes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Skip the GAC, and do use the /codebase option.
2. When you register the .NET assemble using RegAsm, also export the typelib using the `/tlb` option.
3. As a double-check, look in the registry for the objects you just registered in HKCR.
4. In your VB6 project, don't use the `CreateObject` syntax.  Instead, add a refernce to the typelib you exported earlier.

TIP:  Avoid underscores in COM public signatures / class names.  VB6 treats the underscore with special meaning in some  edge cases.  It is best to nip that in the bud.